# Kong 404 not found for static files in index.html

Tags: angular, kong

I am attempting to have Kong proxy the home page request to my upstream service so my upstream service can serve the static files to the client. I currently have the root route (`/$`) imported in kong, and when the client makes a request to the home page e.g. `https://localhost:8443/`, the home page should get served up.

I am running into an issue where my index.html contains hrefs to other assets (this is an Angular app) e.g.

```
    <script src="angular/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/system.src.js"></script>
```

So when the client attempts to access those routes a 404 not found is returned

```
"GET /angular/shim.min.js HTTP/2.0" 404 48 "https://localhost:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
"GET /angular/zone.js HTTP/2.0" 404 48 "https://localhost:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
"GET /angular/Reflect.js HTTP/2.0" 404 48 "https://localhost:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
```

So I only see the text in the `index.html` and not the related assets and images. Weird thing is if i change the route from `/$` to `/` this becomes the [fallback route](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/0.13.x/proxy/#configuring-a-fallback-route) and everything seems to work (because all the hrefs that were 404 now goes to the fallback route). I don't want to do it this way because requests to other services that don't exist will also return the home page for this service. I know that Kong [has the ability to serve up static files](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/configuration/#serving-both-a-website-and-your-apis-from-kong) via NGINX, however, I want my node app to do the files serving and Kong just proxies the files as is.

Do I really need to add all the routes referenced in the index.html in kong for this to work or is there another way?

Comment: I don"t understand your question, you need to configure kong to tell it which path to route to your node. For that you can use regexp, or some directory. On your case for example route all  `/angular/` can do the job

Comment: @Ôrel So does that mean i also have to include all files that the client is trying to access (previously we only import upstream service routes into Kong), e.g. the following are also receiving 404 not found `app.bundle.min.js`, `systemjs.confg.js`, and all node modules, css files and fonts exposed to the client.

Comment: I don't understand why you speak about adding file per file, what is you routing policy if everything should hit the same origin just use `/` without `$` if it is based on subpath use it

Comment: @Ôrel That is what i had before, and it was working (i didn't have to explicitly add all the static files in Kong), but the problem with just using `/` (fallback route) is requests to other services with a non existing route would regex match to `/` and fallback to this service's home page which is not what I want. I have multiple services store in Kong DB. So what happened was, when the client was attempting to make a request to another service with a non-existent route, instead of getting a 404 not found, they will get the `index.html` page, that's why I didn't want to use `/`.

Comment: Sorry still not clear for me. I don"t understand why you get the index.html and not a 404. I don't understand you other service url mapping or configuration. Why '/other_service` will answer index.html ?

Comment: @Ôrel Kong uses regex matching to match routes, if you use `/` any request made to an endpoint that doesn't exist will fallback to `/` which in our case is index.html because that is what express is expecting. So for a request to an endpoint that doesn't exist, the request path goes from `client (request to non-existent path) -> Kong (uses /)  -> Express (index.html)`. https://marcoam-patch-1--kongdocs.netlify.app/2.0.x/proxy/#configuring-a-fallback-route

Comment: At one point you have to choose, or you have fallbaack or you declare the routes, I don"t get which magix you are expecting